# Casting Errors Invalid Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, I would think that adding a cast statement would be easy. However, after researching I am not sure why the code below doesn't work.

Error message: Data loss might occur when casting from NVarChar(100) to VarChar(100).

The Code I am working with:

```
exec dbo.Update
     @customerId,
     @vehicleId,
     @rowNumber output;
```

What I have tried:

```
exec dbo.Update
         @customerId,
         cast(@vehicleId as varchar(100)),
         @rowNumber output;
```

Also Tried:

```
exec dbo.Update
             @customerId,
             cast((@vehicleId) as varchar(100)),
             @rowNumber output;
```

Comment: `NVarchar` contains more data than `varchar`.  To compare it to numbers, it's like trying to cast a `BigInt` into an `Int`.  It's throwing the error because it's possible that data would be lost.

Comment: Yeah, I want to explicitly cast it though. Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you want to cast it? is there a bigger issue that you are encountering that you are trying to solve using casting?

Comment: I need to cast it because the code gives me an error when compiling.

Comment: And what would that error be?

Comment: Error message: Data loss might occur when casting from NVarChar(100) to VarChar(100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little more research and found a solution:

```
declare @tempVehicleId varchar(100);

select @tempVehicleId = cast(@vehicleId as varchar(100))

exec dbo.Update
     @customerId,
     @tempVehicleId,
     @rowNumber output;
```